# Find and return a member of a nested tree

Tags: groovy

Imagine I have a nested tree like this

```
invoices{
    invoice(date: new Date(106,1,2)){

        item(count:5){
            product(name:'ULC', dollar:1499){
                vendor(id:1)
            }
        }
        item(count:1){
            product(name:'Visual Editor', dollar:499){
                vendor(id:3)
            }
        }
    }
    invoice(date: new Date(106,1,2)){
        item(count:4) {
            product(name:'Visual Editor', dollar:499){
                vendor(id:4)
            }
        }
    }
```

and let's assume that I have already turned this into an instance of a list of the invoice class. Now what is the best way for me to return **the** instance of the vendor class in the tree where the id of the vendor is say 3?

This is wrong but something like

Vendor myVendor = invoices*.item*.product*.vendor.find{ i.id == 3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `spread` will collect the attributes into a list, thus, your last `find {}` will be looking for a result in a `list` of `lists`. You can flatten the `vendor` list:

```
def vendor = invoices*.items*.product*.vendor.flatten().find { it.id == 3 }
assert vendor
```